# Dynamic height popup box with floating content boxes and scrollbars if needed

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am currently creating a web-page where popup boxes are opening with dynamic content.

The popup itself should be maximal 98% height of the window -> no content goes on small devices in the overflow.
The content can consist of different elements which are floating and their width is managed by bootstrap columns. Their height should be given by their content, but not exceed the height of the popup. These content boxes can float under each other depending on screensize.

Due to the fact that all content is dynamic and therefore the heights are unknown until all is rendered, there could be scrollbars in almost every box.

```css
html,
body {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
} /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
.clearfix {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css">
  <!-- Favicon -->

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper" style="height: 100%; width; 100%">
    <!-- simple full size wrapper -->
    <div id="dynamicPopup" style="max-height: 98%; background-color: yellow; overflow: auto;" class="clearfix">
      <!-- dynamicPopup - its height depends of content, max height should not exceed 98% of window  -->
      <div id="popupContentWrapper" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"><!-- popupContentWrapper - keeping all popupContents together -->
        <div id="leftContent" class="col-sm-12" style="background-color: red;">
          <!-- leftContent - can be small, but max 100% of height -->FOO</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></div>
        <div id="rightContent" class="col-sm-6" style="height: 100%; background-color: green; overflow: auto;">
          <!-- rightContent - can be small, but max 100% of height, then scrollbar -->
          <div id="rightInnerContent" style="width: 100%; height: 2000px; background-color: green;">BAR</div>
          <!-- rightInnerContent -in this case a very long list which should be create a scrollbar in parent/rightContent -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The example code is only working, when you add a specific height to #dynamicPopup (for ex. 400px).

Is there any way to solve this only with CSS and HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `#wrapper` must have `position: fixed;` so it's height is relative to window not the `body`. then `#dynamicPopup` gonna work the way you expect. this is how popups (modals) work.

here's a good example of what you're trying to achieve:
https://codepen.io/jzilg/pen/vEmQrm

and I have no idea why you have floated your `html` and `body`. I've never seen something like this before. try to avoid it.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#wrapper {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%;
} /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
.clearfix {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css">
  <!-- Favicon -->

</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper" style="height: 100%; width; 100%">
    <!-- simple full size wrapper -->
    <div id="dynamicPopup" style="max-height: 98%; background-color: yellow; overflow: auto;" class="clearfix">
      <!-- dynamicPopup - its height depends of content, max height should not exceed 98% of window  -->
      <div id="popupContentWrapper" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"><!-- popupContentWrapper - keeping all popupContents together -->
        <div id="leftContent" class="col-sm-12" style="height: 49vh; overflow: auto; background-color: red;">
          <!-- leftContent - can be small, but max 100% of height -->FOO</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></div>
        <div id="rightContent" class="col-sm-6" style="height: 49vh; background-color: green; overflow: auto;">
          <!-- rightContent - can be small, but max 100% of height, then scrollbar -->
          <div id="rightInnerContent" style="width: 100%; height: 2000px; background-color: green;">BAR</div>
          <!-- rightInnerContent -in this case a very long list which should be create a scrollbar in parent/rightContent -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The float on body and html were indeed a mistake in my code example. 

The problem in your code and the link you have given is:
#rightInnerContent has a height of 2000px and should force a scrollbar in rightcontent. Because the popup overall should not exceed the 98% of the total height. 

I also played around whith the flex-box example in the link, but i couldn't get it to work.

The problem is, that the children having a relative height of their parent but the parent himself get its own height from the content of the children with a max of 98% of total height.

Comment: @Flo if you have just these two `div`s  (left and right) then set their height to `49vh` when they are stacked and set the height to `98vh` when they are side by side. and don't forget to set `overflow: auto;` vh stands for Viewport Height.

Comment: @Flo I edited my answer, run the code and take a look.

Comment: i still need to detect when my divs are side by side or stacked over each other. Maybe you have some good idea for that.  :)

Comment: you have mentioned "their width is managed by bootstrap columns", each bootstrap column has a breakpoint [(grid options)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#grid-options), so it depends on you which breakpoint to choose. then apply the styles you need using [css media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).